# How to replace some values from one list to another of same type?

Tags: python

I've a problem with arranging and replacing python lists or arrays. 
I've two arrays, let say a and b as,

```
a = [[ 0.   0.  -2.5  0. ]
     [ 0.   0.  -2.   0. ]
     [ 0.   0.  -1.5  0. ]
       ...............,
     [ 2.5  2.   1.   0. ]
     [ 2.5  2.   1.5  0. ]
     [ 2.5  2.   2.   0. ]]
```

There is a total of 300 lines with 4 elements each line. where it arrange as `[ x y z val ]`, 
that means for each x,y,z point I've a value 'val' which initializes as zero for 300 
points. x,y,z have minimum and maximum values x-min = 0, x-max = 2.5; y-min = 0, y-max = 2.0; z-min=-2.5, z-max=2.0.

I've another list, b as

```
b = [[  0.         0.        -2.5       21.793416  ] 
     [  0.         0.5       -2.5       20.30 ] 
     [  0.         1.        -2.5       16.66   ] 
     [  0.         1.5        2.       -16.61 ] 
     [  0.         2.        -2.5        9.06  ] 
     [  0.         2.        -2.         9.81  ] 
     [  0.         2.        -1.5        9.65   ] 
     [  1.5        2.         0.5       -4.42  ] 
     [  1.5        2.         1.        -7.44  ] 
     [  1.5        2.         2.        -8.89  ] 
     [  2.         0.        -2.5       13.26  ] 
     [  2.         0.         1.5       -9.81  ] 
     [  2.5        2.         0.5       -1.60 ]
     [  2.5        2.         1.        -3.48 ]
     [  2.5        2.         2.        -5.20  ]]
```

b is smaller than a (let say 15 points) and have the same type as above `[x y z val]` where the **val** here are not zero.

Now I need to insert the val of `b` for the corresponding x,y,z in to the `a`. That means for equivalent [x y z] points I need to replace the value of val from b to a. Which will modify the list a.

Comment: Just making sure... are all XYZ sets in `a` unique, same for `b`?

Comment: Those seem like NumPy arrays. Are all the points unique? Do you need to use lists/arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming python syntax, you can try something like this :

```
mini_list_a = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z,_ in a]
for x,y,z,val in b:
    a[mini_list_a.index((x,y,z))] = [x,y,z,val]
```

Comment: I'd use a dictionary for the `mini` part. Way faster lookup: `dict_a = dict((tuple(row[:-1]), n) for n, row in enumerate(a))`, and then `a[dict_a((x, y, z)), -1] = val`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing the values in a `dict`, using a tuple of x, y and z as the key?

So you'd have:

```
a = { ( 0. ,  0. , -2.5) : 0. ,
      ( 0. ,  0. , -2. ) : 0. ,
      ( 0. ,  0. , -1.5) : 0. ,
      ...
```

If you make `b` a `dict` in the same format, updating `a` is as simple as:

```
a.update(b)
```

Comment: As long as OP doesn't really need the data to be in an array format, I think this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If x,y,z and val are list items (seperated by comma)

```
a = [[ 0,   0,  -2.5,  0 ]
    [ 0,   0,  -2,   0 ]
    [ 0,   0,  -1.5,  0 ]]

b = [[  0,         0,        -2.5,       21.793416  ] 
    [  0,         0.5,       -2.5,       20.30 ]

for item in a:
    s = filter(lambda x: (x[0]==item[0]and x[1]==item[1] and x[2]==item[2]),b)
    if s:
        item[3] = s[0][3]
```

Using `filter`, you can search for *x,y,z* triple in b, and if found, set the last item (value) as the 3rd value of selected item in a.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `a` and `b` are numpy arrays, you could do it like this:

```
from itertools import imap, izip
index_map = dict(izip(
                   imap(tuple, a[:,0:3].tolist()),
                   xrange(len(a))))

for row in b:
   loc = index_map.get(tuple(row[0:3]))
   if loc is not None:
      a[loc, 3] = row[3]
```

After doing that with the values from above:

```
>>> a
array([[  0.      ,   0.      ,  -2.5     ,  21.793416],
       [  0.      ,   0.      ,  -2.      ,   0.      ],
       [  0.      ,   0.      ,  -1.5     ,   0.      ],
       [  2.5     ,   2.      ,   1.      ,  -3.48    ],
       [  2.5     ,   2.      ,   1.5     ,   0.      ],
       [  2.5     ,   2.      ,   2.      ,  -5.2     ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index_to_a = dict((tuple(row[:3]),row) for row in a)
for x,y,z,val in b:
    index_to_a[x,y,z][3] = val
```